# How do I convert a list of char to a list of integers in R?

Tags: r

```
attach(TexasData)
library(stringr)

years=unlist(str_extract_all(TexasData$Original.License,"[[:digit:]]{4}"))
type.convert(years, na.strings = "NA", as.is = FALSE, dec = ".",
             numerals = c("allow.loss", "warn.loss", "no.loss"))
hist(years)
```

Here is my code, however it still keeps the variable "years" as a list of characters, and histograms will not let your plot that.

Comment: `as.numeric(years)` or if it's a list still then try `as.numeric(unlist(years))`

Comment: you are not saving after the conversion: `years <- type.convert(...)`